# Swift 3 init - unexpected error

Tags: swift, oop, swift3, xcode8

In what I thought was to be a simple subclass, I can't quite seem to figure out the issue.

Does this error message make any sense?

```
'super.init' cannot be called outside of an initializer
```

[image]

Alternatively,

[image]

SKPhoto is declared open, and here are the available inits of the superclass:

```
// MARK: - SKPhoto
open class SKPhoto: NSObject, SKPhotoProtocol {

    open var underlyingImage: UIImage!
    open var photoURL: String!
    open var contentMode: UIViewContentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    open var shouldCachePhotoURLImage: Bool = false
    open var caption: String!
    open var index: Int = 0

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    convenience init(image: UIImage) {
        self.init()
        underlyingImage = image
    }

    convenience init(url: String) {
        self.init()
        photoURL = url
    }

    convenience init(url: String, holder: UIImage?) {
        self.init()
        photoURL = url
        underlyingImage = holder
    }
```

I embarassingly can't solve this problem!

Comment: The compiler is probably displaying the wrong error message.  See [this compiler bug](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2295).  The error messages seem to indicate that SKPhoto does not have an overridable `init()` method.  Is SKPhoto declared `open`?

Comment: In its current form at GitHub, `SKPhoto` [is not `open`, but only `public`](https://github.com/suzuki-0000/SKPhotoBrowser/blob/master/SKPhotoBrowser/SKPhoto.swift): is it possibly you've got the latest version without noticing it?

Comment: SKPhoto is declared open @dfri

Comment: If you test to mark `SKAsset` as `public` instead of `open` (just for testing), do you still get the same error?

Comment: branch 'swift3' is open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a problem in the SKPhoto class; it has not made its init methods open so you can not override them in your sub class;

https://github.com/suzuki-0000/SKPhotoBrowser/blob/swift3/SKPhotoBrowser/SKPhoto.swift

If you really want to use it, you should fork the repo and make appropriate changes, then may use it.

Comment: I was thinking this might be the case. Can you explain why?

Comment: In Swift, default access modifier is internal that can not be accessed outside of the module.